# Separating out d3 Transitions from the rest of the code

Tags: javascript, d3.js, transition

I'm new to java script and d3 and am trying to get my head around transitioning. Would anyone be able to explain why the last segment of code (below) will not work? That is to say when I tie a .transition statement with the original svg call the line transitions fine. But when I transition the yaxis name from "price($)" to "New Price($)" separately nothing happens.

The reason I ask is I'd like to separate the transition call for the line path as well, but if I can't get the axis name to work I don't think I have much hope of the path transition working.

```
 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Price ($)");

 svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line)
  .transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("d",line2);

 svg.append("g")
  .transition()
  .duraction(1000)
  .text("New Price ($)");
```

Comment: You have a typo: `duraction` should be `duration`. But also, what are you trying to transition? Setting the text to something static won't allow it to transition in any way. Also: in order to put text into an SVG element, you need to use the `text` element, not `g`